# Alamofire ServerTrustPolicy always invalidates ServerTrust

Tags: node.js, swift, ssl, alamofire, pinning

I'm using Alamofire on Swift 2.0 and implemented the ServerTrustPolicy for my local server as you can see here:

```
let defaultManager: Alamofire.Manager = {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
//        "localhost": .PinCertificates(
//            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
//            validateCertificateChain: false,
//            validateHost: false
//        )
        "localhost": .DisableEvaluation
    ]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    return Alamofire.Manager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
}()
```

The problem is when I do a request I always get the same error no matter if I use .PinCertificates or .DisableEvaluation:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
UserInfo={
  NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x60c00004d980>,
  NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
  _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
  _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, 
  NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x6060001498a0 [0x10bb3c7b0]>{
    type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
     0 : <cert(0x61600006ed80) s: localhost i: localhost>
    )}, 
   NSUnderlyingError=0x6040000ad750 {
     Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)"
     UserInfo={
       _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
       kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x60c00004d980>,
       _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802,
       _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
       _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802,
       kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x6060001498a0 [0x10bb3c7b0]>{
         type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
           0 : <cert(0x61600006ed80) s: localhost i: localhost>
         )}
     }
   },
   NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:3000/auth/requestToken?auth_appId=d018ccd505db2cb1d5aacabb03fc2f3a,
   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:3000/auth/requestToken?auth_appId=d018ccd505db2cb1d5aacabb03fc2f3a,
   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0
}
```

I tried using

```
curl --cacert ./ca.pem https://localhost:3000
```

which throws works just fine

I use a self signed certificate which I generated like this:

1. Create Root CA private key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out ca.key.pem 2048
   ```
2. Self sign my Root CA

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key.pem -days 1024 -out ca.crt.pem
   ```
3. Create the server certificate by generating the key, then csr, then signing it with the CA

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out server.key.pem 2048
   openssl req -new -key server.key.pem -out server.csr.pem
   openssl x509 -req -in server.csr.pem -CA ca.crt.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server.crt.pem -days 500
   ```

I use nodejs's https module as my web server which I configure like this:

```
require('ssl-root-cas')
  .inject()
  .addFile('./ca.crt.pem');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./server.key.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./server.crt.pem');
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(port);
```

I had a look into the Alamofire source code and found out that in the delegate method:

```
public func URLSession(
        session: NSURLSession,
        didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: ((NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void))
{
    var disposition: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition = .PerformDefaultHandling
    var credential: NSURLCredential?

    if let sessionDidReceiveChallenge = sessionDidReceiveChallenge {
        (disposition, credential) = sessionDidReceiveChallenge(session, challenge)
    } else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        let host = challenge.protectionSpace.host

        if let
            serverTrustPolicy = session.serverTrustPolicyManager?.serverTrustPolicyForHost(host),
            serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        {
            if serverTrustPolicy.evaluateServerTrust(serverTrust, isValidForHost: host) {
                disposition = .UseCredential
                credential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: serverTrust)
            } else {
                disposition = .CancelAuthenticationChallenge
            }
        }
    }

    completionHandler(disposition, credential)
}
```

The call to `serverTrustPolicy.evaluateServerTrust(serverTrust, isValidForHost: host)` actually returns true. This means that the error is probably is happening somwhere in the completionHandler code, right?

Am I doing something terribly wrong at handling the certificate stuff?

PS: `defaultManager` is not beeing deallocated :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your `defaultManager` isn't being deallocated. You'll always get the -999 if it is. With that said, if you use `.DisableEvaluation` then I would assume you have some bigger issues with your SSL configuration server-side.

Are you able to cURL your web service successfully?

I'll update my answer accordingly as you provide more info.

Comment: I added some infos about how I created the certificates, testing using curl and how I set up my web-server :)

Comment: My best guess here is that you don't have any issue with Alamofire. You issue is that your certificate configuration on your servers doesn't seem to be set up quite right. I am not an expert in setting up certificate configurations server-side, so I would encourage you to open a new question on Stack Overflow tailored just to setting up the certificate configuration server-side. Once you have that working, I am assuming Alamofire `ServerTrustPolicies` will just start working. If not, I'll be happy to help you debug then. Best of luck!

Comment: I got the ssl stuff working in curl.. turned out that I made a mistake at generating the certificates. I updated the question with the new problem